# Disabling "Show Backface" en masse for a lot of meshes (Eevee)

Tags: eevee-render-engine, transparency

I'm creating 3D renders in Blender Eevee using game models. However the imported models tend to have 300+ meshes, with a lot of them having broken transparency that is fixed by disabling "Show Backface" in Material Settings. However, manually disabling this for every mesh is very time-consuming. Is there a way to disable this for all meshes? Either that or a way to make it that "Show Backface" is disabled by default?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you mean backface culling you can run this script:

```
import bpy

for eachMat in bpy.data.materials:
    
    eachMat.show_transparent_back = False
```

to set it to false for all materials

Comment: Not quite. I meant "Show Backface", as the transparency of the environment models I'm using break when it's enabled.
[link](https://files.catbox.moe/l58ynn.jpg)

Comment: i updated my answer